# I get the error Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize' in the stack

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Row(
  children: [
    Stack(
      fit: StackFit.loose,
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        activitiesUsers(0,
            'https://images.pexels.com/photos/91227/pexels-photo-91227.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600'),
        activitiesUsers(14,
            'https://images.pexels.com/photos/91227/pexels-photo-91227.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600'),
        activitiesUsers(28,
            'https://images.pexels.com/photos/91227/pexels-photo-91227.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600')
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

```
Positioned activitiesUsers(double positioned, String image) {
  return Positioned(
    left: positioned,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      height: 30,
      width: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: darkblue.withOpacity(0.75),
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Image.network(
          image,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here I call the method I created 3 times in a stack. But **Failed assertion: line 2469 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.** error appears. If I write the Container in the method to the place starting with activitiesUsers(0,), it does not give any error. Why can't I call the first element of the stack with the method I wrote?

Comment: maybe pass the constraints to the positioned instead of the container, Positioned(top: 0, left: positioned, width: 30, height: 30 ....)

Answer (score 0):

Use the constraints in the positioned widget:

```
Positioned activitiesUsers(double positioned, String image) {
    return Positioned(
      left: positioned,
      top: 0,
      height: 30,
      width: 30,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
            color: darkblue.withOpacity(0.75),
          ),
        ),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Image.network(
            image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```